# Extracting elements from a list of size 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have a np array of this type. It is of size 1 but there are 90 numbers in it. Is there any way I can extract all those numbers and save them as a new 1D numpy array?

```
    Array of int64    list    (90,)  A = [7.065590000000000000e+05   7.221840000000000000e+05 
    7.378090000000000000e+05
    1.503434000000000000e+06
    ...
    2.381593400000000000e+07
    2.383155900000000000e+07
    2.384718400000000000e+07]
```

Comment: Will you please print the array e.g. `print(arr)` and send the output? It's almost impossible to answer as-is.

Comment: It is clearly NOT of size 1.  It is a 90-element 1D array.  What makes you think it is size 1?  If you print `array.shape`, you see `(90,)`, right?

Comment: When I output A[1] its says IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get, e.g., the 49th element:

```
A[0][49]
```

To save the numbers in a 1D array, use this:

```
A = A[0]
```

Comment: How can I save all these numbers into a 1 D array that can be callable?

Comment: @sure_sky check the answer now :)

Comment: If I want to replace the zero values of column 9 with 1, on my big numpy array df_array with the index values I obtained above as 1D array of A, how can I do that? for i in A:
    df_array[i,9] == 1   this does not work!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, if all the numbers are separated with spaces, you can use `split()` method in python and and store them individually.

```
s=str(a[0])
x=s.split()
result=map(float, x)
```

you can convert this map object `result` to your required 1D array type.